# How to autoformat (not just auto-indent) in vim?

Tags: windows, vim, code-formatting

Is there a way to let gVim Autoformat my (c#) code? I'm not just talking about indenting, but actually formatting.

Like changing

```
public void Program() {
    ...
}
```

to

```
public void Program ()
{
    ...
}
```

and the other way around. Be it a macro, plugin or something else (formatexpr?).

I'm trying to imitate the Visual Studio formatting here. I'd love to type `}` and have everything look nice.

Comment: You can select a bunch of lines in visual mode and do :'<,'>!indent (with the appropriate arguments). Not sure how useful gnu indent is for C#.

Comment: I guess indent is a cmdline tool? I don't think I have it on my (windows) machine. (Added windows tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim has no native way to do that. However you might be interested in [AStyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) which has [many options](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html)

`astyle --help` will tell you what options are available. Many presets are available.

In vim you can filter a document with `:%!command` where command receives the current buffer in stdin; the current buffer is replaced with the output of your command. If the command does not read from stdin but expects a file name as argument instead, use `%`.

Thus:

```
:%!C:\astyle\bin\astyle.exe -A1
```

will do it (provided you replace with the good path).

Answer (score 0):

The command `gq` formats the code. If you are not happy with standart format rules (`:help formatexpr`) I guess you can use you own code formatter (via `formatprg`) 
To indent C (or similar languages)  you can also read about vim native c-indent, `:help C-indenting`. The cindent method should be able to do what you want.